# Javascript variable contents not accessible in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript function like below.
The first console.log statement works as expected.
However the second console.log statement outputs no values. Could you please help me understand why this is happening. Thanks

```
function testOutputs() {
  let testReasons = []
  
  testScreen.getReasons().find('li').each(($el) => {
    testReasons.push($el.text())
    console.log("Display Array Contents 1 : " + testReasons.toString())
  })
  
  console.log("Display Array Contents 2 : " + testReasons.toString())
}
```

Comment: What's `testScreen.getReasons()`?

Comment: Is `getReasons()` an async function? If so, the second `console.log()` doesn't wait for it to finish.

Comment: Pretty sure there is some asynchronous code involved. Does "Display Array Contents 1" appear before or after "Display Array Contents 2"?